# setTimeout in Node.js loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, settimeout

I'm a bit confused as to how `setTimeout` works. I'm trying to have a `setTimeout` in a loop, so that the loop iterations are, say, 1s apart. 
Each loop iteration makes an HTTP request and it seems like the server on the other end can't handle that many requests in such a short time span.

```
for (var i = 1; i<=2000 && ok; i++) {
    var options = {
        host:'www.host.com',
        path:'/path/'+i
    };

    setTimeout(makeRequest(options, i), 1000);
};
```

Why does this not work and how can I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need something like this

```
var counter = 5;

function makeRequst(options, i) {
    // do your request here
}

function myFunction() {
    alert(counter);

    // create options object here
    //var options = {
    //    host:'www.host.com',
    //    path:'/path/'+counter
    //};
    //makeRequest(options, counter);

    counter--;
    if (counter > 0) {
        setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);    
    }
}
```

See also [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barts2108/tsCqb/4/)

At the point of the `alert(count);` you can do your call to the server.
Note that the counter works opposite (counting down). I updated with some
comments where to do your thing.

Comment: Welcome. If your request to the server is not time critical, you even better use a construction where a new timer is only started after the previous server call has finished. Then only one server call will be active even if the call takes more than 1 second (the setTimeout timer value)

Comment: **WARNIG**: Your solution can lead to a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Please see [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30575612/1480391) that uses `setImmediate`. BTW OP is using Node.js.. (there is no `alert` in Node.js).

Comment: @Yves M. : The `setTimeout()` should be sufficient. There is no recursive call to `myFunction` in this solution.

Comment: If I look at [this API document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate) the **note** tells me that `setImmediate` might not become standard, althoug it existis in node.js

Comment: @MikeTunnicliffe `myFunction` calls `setTimeout` which calls `myFunction` again.. and so on. This is called recursion. Try your code with 30,000 times (and 1ms to be quick)

Comment: @Yves M : `myFunction` passes a reference to itself (a named function) to `setTimeout`, it does not call itself. If the invocation were `setTimeout(myFunction(), 1000);` you would be correct.

Comment: @barts This is a Node.js question... `setImmediate` exists, the documentation is [here](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg). If you want to use it browser side, you can still use [this implementation of setImmediate](https://github.com/YuzuJS/setImmediate).

Comment: @MikeTunnicliffe It doesn't matter how long is the snake.. if the snake eats it's own tail, it's recursion :) Please test your code (display the call stack at each `myFunction` call and you will se the call stack growing)

Comment: @MikeTunnicliffe Of course `setTimeout` calls the function you give to it. Otherwise it's complete non sense. From the [Mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout): _**Calls a function** or executes a code snippet after a specified delay_

Comment: @Yves M.: I agree, `setTimeout` calls the function you give it, but in Node it does so on a different iteration of the event loop and so `myFunction` doesn't in fact call itself. For example, doing a straight recursive call fails for me after 20 929 calls. Using setTimeout it's cleared 500 000 calls with no sign of failing.

Comment: @MikeTunnicliffe Yes sorry my bad :D setTimeout does clear the call stack.. I'm sorry. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058612/does-calling-settimeout-clear-the-callstack :D Your code does not stack overflow... :)

Comment: Nice discussion here. Please leave the comments here for future reference. other people might benefit from it

Answer (score 16):

[setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_arg) is **non blocking**, it is asynchronous. You give it a callback and when the delay is over, your callback is called.

Here are some implementations:

## Using recursion

You can use a [recursive call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) in the `setTimeout` callback.

```
function waitAndDo(times) {
  if(times < 1) {
    return;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {

    // Do something here
    console.log('Doing a request');

    waitAndDo(times-1);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Here is how to use your function:

```
waitAndDo(2000); // Do it 2000 times
```

**About stack overflow errors**: `setTimeout` clear the call stack (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058612/does-calling-settimeout-clear-the-callstack)) so you don't have to worry about stack overflow on `setTimeout` recursive calls.

## Using generators (io.js, ES6)

If you are already using [io.js](https://iojs.org) (the "next" Node.js that uses [ES6](https://iojs.org/en/es6.html)) you can solve your problem without recursion with an elegant solution:

```
function* waitAndDo(times) {
  for(var i=0; i<times; i++) {

    // Sleep
    yield function(callback) {
      setTimeout(callback, 1000);
    }    

    // Do something here
    console.log('Doing a request');
  }
}
```

Here is how to use your function (with [co](https://github.com/tj/co)):

```
var co = require('co');

co(function* () {
  yield waitAndDo(10);
});
```

BTW: This is really using a loop ;)

[Generator functions documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

Answer (score 3):

Right now you're scheduling all of your requests to happen at the same time, just a second after the script runs.  You'll need to do something like the following:

```
var numRequests = 2000,
    cur = 1;

function scheduleRequest() {
    if (cur > numRequests) return;

    makeRequest({
        host: 'www.host.com',
        path: '/path/' + cur
    }, cur);

    cur++;
    setTimeout(scheduleRequest, 1000)
}
```

Note that each subsequent request is only scheduled after the current one completes.

Comment: that's what I thought as well

Comment: @jmar777 I realize that this is an old post, however I am having a similar issue. Do you mind answering why the `scheduleRequest` function doesn't pass `cur` or `numRequests`?

Answer (score 3):

I might be late at the party but here is another (more readable) solution without the need to omit `for` loop.

What your code does is creating 2000 (actually 1999) `setTimeout` objects that will call the `makeRequest` function after 1 second ***from now***. See, none of them knows about the existence of the other `setTimeout`s.

If you want them 1 sec apart from each other, you are responsible for creating them so.

This can be achieve by using your ***counter*** (in this case `i`) and the timeout ***delay***.

```
for (var i = 1; i<=2000 && ok; i++) {
    var options = {
        host:'www.host.com',
        path:'/path/'+i
    };

    setTimeout(makeRequest(options, i), i * 1000); //Note i * 1000
};
```

The first timeout object will be set for *1 second* from now and the second one will be set for *2 seconds* from now and so on; Meaning ***1 second*** apart from each other.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that no one has mentioned this above, but it sounds like you need setInterval not setTimeout.

```
vat poller = setInterval(makeRequestFunc, 3000)
```

The code above will make a request every 3 seconds. Since you saved the object to the variable `poller`, you can stop polling by clearing the object like so:

```
cleanInterval(poller)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling makeRequest() in your setTimeout call - you should be passing the function to setTimeout, not calling it, so something like

```
setTimeout(makeRequest, 1000);
```

without the ()

Answer (score 0):

```
        let i = 20;
        let p = Promise.resolve(i)
        while (i > 0) {
        (i => {
            p = p.then(() => {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log(i);
                resolve()
                }, 2000)
            })
            })
        })(i)
        i--
        }
        p = p.then(data => console.log('execution ends'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late on the subject (as usual ...;) but the only way I found to loop requests to a slow time response API and getting responses without HTTP 504 is using promises.

```
async function LoadDataFromAPI(myParametersArray) {
    for(var i = 0; i < myParametersArray.length; i++) { 
        var x = await RunOneRequest(myParametersArray[i]); 
        console.log(x); // ok
    }
}
```

The function called by the async function :

```
function RunOneRequest(parameter) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            request(parameter, (error, response, body) => {
                // your request
            });
        resolve('ok);
        }, 2000); // 2 secs
    });
}
```