# setTimeout in nodejs - for loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have looked over this post: [setTimeout in Node.js loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682524/settimeout-in-nodejs-loop) in hopes that it would solve my issue, and in a way it has. However, I am encountering a new issue that I am unable to resolve on my own.

I have been trying to fix this issue for the past couple of hours, but I have had no luck. Here is what I have:

The function that needs to be called in the timeout function:

```
function searchLDAP(i, app, userUID){
    app.process_args(userUID[i]);
}
```

This is the portion of the code that is not working properly. The code works for the first iteration (`userUID[0]`), however when it tries to recurse, `i` becomes `undefined`.

```
function doSetTimeout(i, count, app, userUID) {
    if(i == count - 1){ callback(); }    
    searchLDAP(i, app, userUID);

    ++i;
    setTimeout(doSetTimeout, 2000);
}
```

I am using node's async module

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        app.readLines(input, callback); // userUID is and array that 
                                        // is returned from this function
    },
    function() {
        var count = userUID.length;
        var i = 0;
        doSetTimeout(i, count, app, userUID);
    }
    ], function(err) {
        console.log('all functions complete');
});
```

Thank you in advance

-Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `setTimeout`, you only command which function should be called, but do not pass the set of arguments that the function should use. And here's one possible approach to solve this problem:

```
function doSetTimeout(i, count, app, userUID) {
    if (i == count - 1) { 
      return; // you should stop the recursion
    }

    searchLDAP(i, app, userUID);

    setTimeout(function() {
      doSetTimeout(i + 1, count, app, userUID);
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: When I do this, it only returns information for the last element in the array. For example, if I have 5 `userUID`s that need to be passed, it will call `searchLDAP()`5 times, however it will only use `userUID[4]`, not `userUID[0]` then `userUID[1]` ... etc

Comment: How exactly does the app `return` information? Wasn't your question about solving the problem with `setTimeout`?

Comment: lol, I misread your answer. It worked. Thank you for your help. I was forgetting to put in `function(){...}` before calling `doSetTimeout`

Comment: No problem, that's ok. Indeed, it's too easy both to forget how to end the recursion, and how to start it. )

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to raina77ow's answer, you can also better use async (and dramatically reduce complexity and lines of code) like this:

```
app.readLines(input, function(err, users) {
    async.each(users, function(user, next) {
        app.process_args(user);
        next();
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('all functions complete');
    });
});
```

This will iterate over each of your users (the userUID array from you post), and pass the value to the function. No need to mess with tracking the value of i yourself. This isn't rate limited and doens't have the setTimeout which is only necessary if your process_args method cannot handle concurrent calls. If you need make sure that there is only one app.process_args being called at a time, you can use eachSeries instead:

```
app.readLines(input, function(err, users) {
    async.eachSeries(users, function(user, next) {
        app.process_args(user);
        next();
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('all functions complete');
    });
});
```

And if for some reason you *really* need a two second delay between calls, you can do the following:

```
app.readLines(input, function(err, users) {
    async.eachSeries(users, function(user, next) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            app.process_args(user);
            next();
        }, 2000);
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('all functions complete');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try this method as well.