# React 0.13 this.getDOMNode() equivalent to React.findDOMNode()

Tags: reactjs

This works perfectly fine in React version 0.12:

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    var dom = this.getDOMNode();
}
```

The variable `dom` gets the actual DOM node for the rendered component.  However, converting this to React 0.13 does not work as expected:

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    var dom = React.findDOMNode();
    // dom is undefined
}
```

I tried `React.findDOMNode(this)` which does not work either.  Basically I'm just trying to fetch the top-level dom node rendered by the render function without using a ref.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Update React v0.14+**

In React v0.14+ [this has changed](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#two-packages-react-and-react-dom), you should now use the [`react-dom`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html) module:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
```

**ES6**

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    console.log(element);
    alert(element);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>test</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('r'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="r" />
```

**ES5**

```js
var Test = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var dom = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    console.log(dom);
    alert(dom);
  },
  render: function() {
    return React.createElement('div', null, 'test');
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Test), document.getElementById('r'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="r" />
```

---

**React v0.13 and below**

Passing this as the parameter should definitely work:

```
React.findDOMNode(this);
```

If not, something else may be going on. See demo below:

```js
var Test = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var dom = React.findDOMNode(this);
    console.log(dom);
    alert(dom);
  },
  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.div(null, 'test');
  }
});

React.render(React.createElement(Test), document.getElementById('r'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/react.js"></script>
<div id="r"></div>
```

Answer (score 42):

Note that as of React v0.14

`React.findDOMNode` becomes `ReactDom.findDOMNode(this);` where

```
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
```

As explained in https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html

Answer (score 17):

React 15.0.1 Requires this syntax: `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`

e.g.

```
var x = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.author);
```

Answer (score 2):

For more complex elements like React components  created on standard DOM elements `refs` give us only first DOM element ( root element of component ) so sometimes we need to find desired node inside it. Good example is **Material-Ui TextField** component and how we can get value from it.

1.Required imports

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

2.Virtual dom and `ref="variable"`

```
 <TextField floatingLabelText="Some title" ref="title" />
```

3.Query inside TextField:

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.title).querySelector("input").value
```

or for multiline:

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.title).querySelector("textarea").value
```

We start from `TextField` container and using standard DOM query `querySelector` get wanted input element. This solution is working with any complexed components, we always can query inside it. Tested on React **(15.3.2).**

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't need to use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`, you can use simple `e.target.innerHTML`. In this option you don't need to import `ReactDOM`.