# How can I get the coordinates of a given element in react tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using React with Typescript and would like to know how to figure out the coordinates of a sub-component in a React class I wrote.

I already found this article: https://medium.com/@chung.andrew7/finding-the-absolute-positions-of-react-components-fda1c5bc9ab

And this: [Get div's offsetTop positions in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667847/get-divs-offsettop-positions-in-react)

Here it is stated that this is usually done with `getBoundingClientRect()`, but I can't find any way how to do this with TypeScript, or what property or a `ref` this would be located on.

If I assign my component as `_searchBarPreview: React.RefObject<{}>;` by passing the following as "ref" prop on the element:`ref={this._searchBarPreview}`, I can't access the said function on that object at all.

What works is to assign the child component I want to get clients of an id and obtain the coordinates via:

```
document.getElementById('blablablablabla').getBoundingClientRect();
```

but there HAS to be a better way.

Any quick guidance?

Comment: Can you specify React, Typescript versions.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like that is the only way or you can use react-dom

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.myRef = React.createRef()
    const data = ReactDOM
      .findDOMNode(this.myRef)
      .getBoundingClientRect();
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />
  }
}
```