# React - Uncaught TypeError: this.getDOMNode is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to apply styling through jquery in react component however i'm getting error `Uncaught TypeError: this.getDOMNode is not a function`

```
topicsVisited(arr){
         $(function() {
          $.each(arr, function(key, eachVisitedTopic) {
            console.log(eachVisitedTopic);
            $(this.getDOMNode()).find('.single-topic[data-topic-id="' + eachVisitedTopic + '"]').css({
              'background-color': 'red'
            });
          });
        });
      };
```

Comment: what react version do you use?

Comment: @Alexander I'm using react 0.14.7

Comment: Seems like [the same. Use ReactDom.findDOMNode(this). See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33568298)

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your functions in order to use `this` properly.

```
topicsVisited(arr) {
    $(function() {
        $.each(arr, function(key, eachVisitedTopic) {
            console.log(eachVisitedTopic);
            $(this.getDOMNode()).find('.single-topic[data-topic-id="' + eachVisitedTopic + '"]').css({'background-color': 'red'});
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this);
}
```

or create a variable that references the correct `this`.

```
topicsVisited(arr) {
    var self = this;
    $(function() {
        $.each(arr, function(key, eachVisitedTopic) {
            console.log(eachVisitedTopic);
            $(self.getDOMNode()).find('.single-topic[data-topic-id="' + eachVisitedTopic + '"]').css({'background-color': 'red'});
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Now i'm getting 2 errors `Warning: getDOMNode(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React classes. Use ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component) instead.` and `Uncaught TypeError: self.getDOMNode is not a function`

Comment: Yes, `getDOMNode` is deprecated in favour of `findDOMNode` from the `react-dom` package. `npm install react-dom --save` and change from `this.getDOMNode()` to `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(self)` will do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
topicsVisited(arr){
         var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
         var self = this;
         $(function() {
          $.each(arr, function(key, eachVisitedTopic) {
            console.log(eachVisitedTopic);
            $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(self)).find('.single-topic[data-topic-id="' + eachVisitedTopic + '"]').css({
              'background-color': 'red'
            });
          });
        });
      };
```

Comment: Still not working although it not showing any error in console. console.log output `[prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: div.row, selector: ".single-topic[data-topic-id="4"]"]`

Comment: I think the styling is getting overridden while mount and unmounting of components.