# reactjs is it possible to get a notification after the DOM is updated?

Tags: dom, reactjs, lifecycle

I have a component which renders a list of up to a thousand elements.

It takes 3/5 seconds to update the DOM, I mean after the component event componentDidUpdate, which is called after the changes have been flushed to the DOM, it takes 3/5 seconds to actually see the DOM updated.

I would like to show a spinning cog or something, but I don't know how, because I don't know how to get notified when the DOM updated is complete.

Anyone knows?

Comment: If a browser is busy doing DOM operations (or evaluating JS in general) - the spinner will not animate.

Comment: Right, I tend to forget that part. Still, as @Andy-Ray is suggesting I could show something, like "please wait" without spinner, and remove it after the DOM is actually updated, if only I had a mean of knowing when the DOM is finally updated. But I can't figure out how. Unless I do something ugly, like polling/setTimeOut to check if the DOM changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is single threaded, and all DOM operations are blocking. That means if the browser is busy adding to and updating the DOM, this will lock the Javascript thread until the DOM is updated. During the actual update, there's nothing you can do in code.

This is assuming the UI lockup is actually from a raw, very large amount of DOM manipulation, and not some other underlying culprit. @zerkms's comment is also accurate that animated gifs, CSS animations, etc, generally do not run while the browser is locked up performing large calculations.

If you anticipate browser lockup, the simplest solution is to show some spinner overlay, *then* run the command that updates your data. This way the spinner will already be in the DOM. When the update has completed, you can remove the spinner. It might look something like

```
render() {
    return <div>
        <div onClick={ this.performLongRunningAction }>click me</div>
        { this.state.spinnerVisible ? 'Loading' : null }
    </div>
}

performLongRunningAction() {

    // First show the spinner...
    this.setState({ spinnerVisible: true }, () => {

        // Then after state has been set and spinner rendered, start the
        // long action
        executeLongRunningActionNow();

    });

}

// Then you need some mechanism to turn off the spinner state after the
// task has completed
componentWillReceiveProps( nextProps ) {

    // Did a task execute? Turn off the spinner before the next render
    if( nextProps.someCompletedFlag !== this.props.someCompletedFlag ) {
        this.setState({ spinnerVisible: false });
    }

}
```

Another solution is to break up the updating into chunks, so you update the DOM in intervals that are minimal enough not to lock up the Javascript thread. You have provided code, so fleshing out this solution is not possible.

Comment: Ok, I can show the spinner before the "render". But since the lockup is occurring after "componentDidUpdate", when the changes have been flushed to the DOM, how can I get a notification to turn off the spinner? My only idea right now is polling/setTimeOut to check if the DOM actually changed, which seems so terrible.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34999925/395773) from another question is what helps here.