# React > How to set focus on the input field after adding a new row by using react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-ref

I decided to use `react-table` to build the grid.

Just one thing to have better UI, that is I want to focus on the input field of the new item after clicking on the add new button.

I intend to use `ref` but have no idea how `fowardRef` to the child item

Here is my example use of react-table:

https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-proskuriakova-lpfxn

In this case, I want to focus on the field `First Name` after adding a new row.

[image]

**UPDATED:**
I am able to focus on the input by using `autoFocus` support by native HTML.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54159564/4886453)

But I still want to handle focus by using `React Ref`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used plain `JavaScript` to acheive your goal

```
  const setFocus = () => {
    //Add id to the table
    document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")[0].setAttribute("id", "mytable");

    //table > tbody > tr (latest added row) > td (first cell in the row) > input
    let cell = document.getElementById("mytable").lastElementChild
      .lastElementChild.firstElementChild.children[0];

    cell.focus();
  };

  const addNew = () => {
    setData(old => [...old, {}]);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(setFocus);
  };
```

[image: Edit Editable with react-table]

I used `requestAnimationFrame` because I was manipulating the DOM, Checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28748160/12461764) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to apply `forwardRef()` on functional component and React doc says

> You may not use the ref attribute on function components [React ref doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs)

You can use `useImeprativeHandle()` which can be;

```
const Table = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    focus: () => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }), []);
  return <Editable ref={inputRef} {...props} />;
}
```

Now you are able to reach ref with creating ref and call the imperative's method. I did not look how to focus your element but you can handle `forwardRef` problem by using imperativeHandle.

### OR

You can convert your EditTable component to classed based comp.

Answer (score 0):

Plain and simple autoFocus worked for me in the text box.