# Checking the current day with moment.js does not update on new day

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

In a Node application I have a function that runs every 30 seconds.

It prints to the console using `moment().day()`.  I let it run over night and expected it to notice that the day is now `5` instead of `4` signifying that it is now Friday rather than Thursday.  It continued to print `4` when I checked this morning.  Why would this be?

Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9ya2auzy/2/

```
function checkTheDay(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = moment().day(); 
    checkTheDay();
  }, 2000);
}

checkTheDay();
```

It will output the current day every 2 seconds.  If the page is left open, it should run over night and then print the next number, `6` (at the time of writing) rather than the current ouput `5` (at the time of writing).

Comment: @Andreas does my edit make my problem statement more clear?

Comment: Maybe a timezone problem ?

Comment: @Weedoze - it *could* be related to time zones, if the time zone setting of the computer where this is running is not the same as the OP's local time zone.  I suppose if this is code running on a server, where the server is set to UTC or some other time zone, then that might explain it. But we didn't get any information about that from the question.  Perhaps the OP could check the output of `moment().format()` to see the result with full time and time zone offset included.  That would be useful to diagnose.

Comment: It is an electron app, so the server is actually still on the client's machine.  They should both be reading the same timezone info.

Comment: Then it cannot be time zone related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're recursing into the `checkTheDay` function once every two seconds.  Over a long enough period of time, you're going to exhaust the call stack.

Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` and then you will not need to recurse.

```
function checkTheDay(){
    setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = moment().day(); 
  }, 2000);
}

checkTheDay();
```

You can see the effects of the stack growing in your original fiddle by using the Chrome debugger, setting a breakpoint, and looking at the call stack (upper right in the screenshots below).

**First Iteration:**

[image: First Iteration]

**Second Iteration:**

[image: Second Iteration]

**Third Iteration:**

[image: Third Iteration]

As you can see, the call stack is growing.  Left unchecked, it will grow out of control until it becomes unresponsive or throws an error.

Comment: If there is some potentially long running task inside the `setInterval` then they will start stacking on each other.  I am using `setTimeout` to ensure that the task can finish before starting the next iteration.

Comment: Well, that wasn't part of your question, but you can handle that with a simple `inProgress` flag you set true/false and check to skip any iterations if another iteration is not complete.  But you can't just recurse infinitely, or you'll run out of resources one way or another.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058612/does-calling-settimeout-clear-the-callstack

I should not have to worry about he call stack growing too large.

Comment: Your code is different than the code in that sample, because you are using recursion.  See my update for proof.

Comment: I see.  You are right.  I will have to investigate this farther and see if that is the root cause.  I will use `setInterval` over the weekend and see if that gives me back the correct day.

Comment: There's no recursion in the code of the TO... `function a() { a(); }` that would be recursion. Check the callstack in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kodw437p/): `function a() { setTimeout(a, 1000); } a();` - @wrldbt Yes, you don't have to worry about the call stack, as you've already seen in the answer of your link

Comment: It seems that using setInterval was able to log the correct day.  I'm still not sure if the call stack is the culprit though.

Comment: Regardless of possible recursion, I accepted the answer because changing it to `setInterval` fixed my problem.